# Custom Raw File Path - Android

Tags: android, path

In my raw folder I have a number of folders, how can I target these, Ive tried a path var as below but no luck:

```
String path = "R.raw.myFolder";
mSoundManager.addSound(1, path.myFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why you have folders inside your raw folder. That folder is there to store the media you need. Do not over complicate the project by having to reference a folder name on top of the file name. the code below is for accessing files straight out of the raw folder.

Try giving this a go:

```
mSoundManager.addSound("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+ "/" + R.raw.filename);
```

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for but this is what works for me for all my raw files.

I left out a piece. Code is now correct.

Comment: No, not what im looking for. I need to add a folder after the raw:

Comment: So it needs to be R.raw.mysubfolder.myresource

Comment: Ok, then can you explain the purpose of this subfolder? I am not seeing the functionality of an extra folder in the raw folder. If it's for organization, then you are causing yourself too much pain.

Comment: Its so I can change the path dynamically

Comment: Ok, I see. Well sorry I couldn't give you a better answer :/